# From Europe to Australia by car

Tags: china, driving, australia, ferries

We're planning a trip by car (a converted van) from Europe to Australia in 2019. There are 2 items which seem to make our plans a little bit more impossible: driving through China (Chinese driving license, plate etc) and finding a car passenger ferry from somewhere in Asia to somewhere in Australia. If you would have any tips for us, we would be really greatful!

Comment: Car passenger ferry from Asia to Australia?  I *think* you'll be out of luck.  May need to ship the car and travel separately

Comment: You'll find this is a much more difficult prospect than initially appears.  Have you considered shipping the van to Australia and taking trains through Asia?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. This is two completely separate questions.